AWS eu-south-1 not supporting VPC endpoint for SES
I'd like to set up a VPC endpoint to AWS SES to send emails from EC2 instances set in a private subnet (and therefore without public IPs).
Unluckily it seems that VPC endpoint for SES is not supported in the region eu-south-1 (Milan), and VPC endpoints currently do not support cross-region requests.
So, is there any other way to send email from private subnet EC2 without using a NAT gateway?
By the way, why this region don't support some VPC endpoints? Are they going to be implemented later on?

Just for reference, Amazon Simple Email Service endpoints and quotas - AWS General Reference says: "SMTP endpoints are not currently available in Africa (Cape Town), Asia Pacific (Jakarta), Europe (Milan), Israel (Tel Aviv), Middle East (Bahrain)."

Did you find documentation that says that SES VPC Endpoints aren't supported in eu-south-1? The AWS documentation only lists a handful of AZs.

@John Rotenstein
Yes: SMTP endpoint is not available in Europe, so you have to use SES SDK, but both (SMTP and API) require to pass through Internet; instead I'm interested in a VPC endpoint that is recheable inside your VPC.

@jarmod I just tried to add a VPC endpoint from VPC console in Region eu-south-1 but I couldn't find any SES endpoint among the listed ones.

I think that the reason for which SES VPC endpoint is not supported in eu-south-1 AWS region is because SES generally only supports SMTP endpoints and not API endpoints (eg in eu-central-1 the only VPC endpoint is com.amazonaws.eu-central-1.email-smtp).
So, since in eu-south-1 AWS region SES SMTP endpoint is not available and API endpoint is the only available, then there can't be a VCP endpoint at all.
The solution is to use AWS VPC peering to connect to a second VPC that support SES VPC endpoint, in which you can set it.
